# Distributed transaction mysql java connector

Tags: java, mysql, distributed-transactions

We have an application where we need to read from a table and update its status and insert the read values into another remote db. In this case both the tables are mysql based. How ensure both are control via a transaction thus if it failed to insert then the update should be rollback on the local machine?

Comment: Can you let the app code handle the multi db transaction?

Comment: @Bohemian yes I want the app code to handle is that possible?